# How to exploit bilinearity on the following expression - dot product

Tags: analytic-geometry, inner-products, bilinear-form

I struggle to apply the concept of bilinearity to follow along with simplifying the following expression bellow.

\begin{align}\langle x-\pi_{U}(x),\space b \rangle  \space= \space0\iff\langle x-\lambda,\space b\rangle = 0\space\space(1)\end{align}

where $\pi_{U}(x)=\lambda b$ can be simplified by applying bilinearity to this:

\begin{align}\langle x,b\rangle-\lambda\langle b,b\rangle =0\space\space(2)\end{align}

From the book mathematics for machine learning page 83. The [book](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf) is publicly available

Can you explain the steps between these expressions?

Comment: What is bilinearity?

Comment: @blamethelag linearity in each argument

Comment: Then put the missing $b$ in (1) and apply the linearity to the left argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's really simple.

$\langle x-\lambda b, \space b \rangle = \langle x,b \rangle + \langle -\lambda b,\space b\rangle =\langle x, b\rangle-\lambda\langle b, b\rangle$

Found out that the lambda can be moved in and out which added some intuition for me. At first I thought I have to combine the two equations.

Comment: Your first equality is false, perhaps you meant $\langle x,b \rangle + \langle -\lambda b,b \rangle$.

Comment: @blamethelag you're right, fixed it